# AspNet Core Localizing Navigation Proerties

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, data-annotations, navigation-properties

I am trying to localize nav properties in my models. Simple properties work just fine, but for some reason, the schema I use for localizing these doesn't work for nav properties.

```
services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddViewLocalization(
        LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
        opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
opts =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("de-DE")
    };

    opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE");
    opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    opts.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
    };
});
```

This is how I configure my localization. I then created a folder `Resources` and created a bunch of .resx files inside it that mirror the file and folder structures of my models.

[image]

[image]

This is my `CompanyViewModel`

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("CompanyID")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    //...

    public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

And this the corresponding `AddressViewModel`

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("AddressID")]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Line1")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

It seems no matter what I do, when I display the Address property in views, it doesn't show the localized strings, just the property name. I have tried using multiple naming schemes like `Address.Lin1` or creating resources like `CompanyViewModel.Address.de-DE.resx`. But nothing I do will show anything other than the property name.

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

EDIT: Here is how I render the AddressViewModel:

```
<p>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Address.AddressID" />
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            @Localizer["AddressDetails"]
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <dl class="form-row">
                <dt class="form-group col-md-6">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.Line1)
                </dt>
                <dd class="form-group col-md-6">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address.Line1)
                </dd>
                ...
```

Comment: Can you show how are you rendering AddressID and Line1 on the View?

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I would say that you are actually keeping localization strings in the wrong resx file. Localization that is related to AddressViewModel should be in AddressViewModel.resx in the same path where your AddressViewModel is stored, regardless of the fact that AddressViewModel is the property of CompanyViewModel.

With further testing, I noticed that localization won't work if namespace is not the same as the resx folder structure.

So in my example I had following structure:

[image]

which didn't work if my ChildViewModel wasn't in LocalizationTest.Models.ChildModel namespace. I put it first in LocalizationTest.Models and it didn't work.

Comment: I already do it like this. `AddressViewModel.de-DE.resx` is located inside the `AddressManagement` subfolder of the `Resources` folder. I have updated the image in my question to clarify this.

Comment: BTW, you did say that you did some testing. Did you manage to make DataAnnotation localization work with nav properties? If yes, can you please share the code somehow?

Comment: Hey, yes my example worked just fine. I can share it a bit later with you. What I did use though is a bit different, I used <label asp-for="Address.AddressID"/> and @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address.AddressID) and both worked.

Comment: I solved it. Stupid me put a typo into the namespace of the AddressViewModel. I swear to god...XD

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is stupid of me but I am gonna post it anyway. My problem was a typo in the namespace of my `AddressViewModel`. We renamed our project not too long ago and although I did a search and replace, I must have still managed to somehow screw that up.